# Ver el histórico de cambios usando GIT

Tags: git

¿Cómo puedo ver el histórico de cambios para un archivo en Git, junto con los cambios en cada commit?

He utilizado:

```
git log -- [filename]
```

el cual me muestra el histórico de commits sobre el archivo, pero no el contenido de cada cambio por commit.

Comment: Algo relacionado: `git blame <archivo>` te muestra cual fue el ultimo commit que modifico cada linea del archivo, linea x linea.  Es muy util para localizar quien/cuando se modifico una linea de código especifica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acuerdo con la documentación oficial de git-log (`man git-log`) puedes hacer uso de 2 argumentos útiles:

> - `--follow`: Continua el listado del historial de un archivo, detrás de los renombres (trabaja sólo con archivos únicos).
> - `-p, -u, --patch`: Generará los parches (ver sección: «generating patches»).

```
git log --follow -p [filename]
```

---

#### Modo gráfico

(autor: [@Tim Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper))

Puedes utilizar el comando:

```
gitk [filename]
```

---

Hay información en este pregunta (en inglés) similar a la tuya: [View the change history of a file using Git versioning - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278192/view-the-change-history-of-a-file-using-git-versioning).

Comment: Esto no lo sabía Chofo: "git log --follow -p <archivo>" pero por ejemplo un archivo .xml o .txt me muestra todo el contenido =), creo que yo opto por gitk <ruta/archivo>

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago para realizar esa tarea es lo siguiente:

- Cuando preparo mis ficheros para subirlos al `HEAD`, uso `git commit -m "algún mensaje" -v` lo que hace `-v` provoca que se añadan las diferencias de tus cambios realizados.
- Luego de subirlos uso el siguiente comando `git log -c`  lo cual te muestra todos los `commits` del último hasta el primer `commit`, realizados al archivo con su respectivos cambios, además de unos datos adicionales, como el `index`,las `inserciones` y demás.

Answer (score 0):

Se realiza con el comando:

```
gitk <path>
```

> Muestra los cambios en un repositorio o un conjunto seleccionado de
>   commits. Esto incluye la visualización de la gráfica cometer, que
>   muestra la información relacionada con cada confirmación, y los
>   archivos de los árboles de cada revisión.

Documentación [**gitk**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)